# How to interact with a console application on Windows with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to write a simple script that interacts with a console application on Windows.

The thing is that the application doesn't take args, so something like this

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["application.exe", "command1", "command2"])
```

doesn't work.

I also tried using subproccess.PIPE, but it didn't work either. Here is my attempt at that:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("application.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('command1\n'.encode('utf-8'))
result1 = p.stdout.read()
p.stdin.write('command2\n'.encode('utf-8'))
result2 = p.stdout.read()
```

I don't want to terminate the proccess. Is there any way to do that? Am I missing something?

Any help will be appreciated.

UPD:

Important to mention that the application itself is interactive.

So I have this code and as output it prints "Here" and freezes.
No errors at all. So everything freezes after `out = p.stdout.read()` line.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("APP.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
p.stdin.write('COMMAND1\n'.encode('utf-8'))
p.stdin.write('COMMAND2\n'.encode('utf-8'))
print("Here")
out = p.stdout.read()
print(out)
```

Same thing was when I tried `out = subprocess.check_output(["application.exe"])` it just freezed and nothing happend after it.

When I tried passing commands through `APP.exe < Commands.txt` it worked perfectly fine. So i had just `Command1\nCommand2\n` in txt file and got needed output.

Comment: what about `out = subprocess.check_output(["application.exe"])`

Comment: maybe first check if you can do it directly in console `application.exe < file_with_commands`. If this doesn't work then application can't get from PIPE.

Comment: if you want to more complex interaction then you may try module [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) (or program `expect` on Linux) - but it will not work if program can't read from PIPE.

Comment: @furas yes, i just checked and it works, so I think PIPE is a way to go. Now I just need to figure out why it doesn't work with my implementation.

Comment: @BijayRegmi No, it doesn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: we can't run you code so you have describe all detaisl - what means `didn't work` ? Do you get error message when you run it? Show FULL error in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Is code freeze? You could use `print()` to see which line is executed and which stops program. And you should see what you get in `result`. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked out when I added `p.communicate()` after writing to stdin the needed commands.

So working code looks like this right now

```
p = subprocess.Popen("APP.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
p.stdin.write('command1\n'.encode('utf-8'))
p.stdin.write('command2\n'.encode('utf-8'))
Output = p.communicate().decode('utf-8')
```